Android studio after updating to Iguana not allowing to create flutter project
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11668458, built on April 4, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Non-Bundled Plugins:
Dart (232.10313)
wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)
io.flutter (79.0.1)enter image description here
How to create flutter project in this version of Android Studio?

simply on the left side click on flutter icon and then. continue as normal.
Happy Coding :)
